# PHPExcel how to detect if a loaded view used specific `fontAwesome` icon, and write that?

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-excel

I'm using `Laravel-Excel`, When I load a view and parse that with `DOMDocument` then i write them to specific row and cell of table, now if on the view a column uses from `fa-check-square-o` icon, how i should detect that ? and how i should write that ? I think only we can check it's unicode for this, am I write ?

Comment: Unicode chars are plain chars - you could check for them like for any other char.

Comment: No spreadsheet file formats that I'm aware of will recognise fontawesome in any way

Comment: @MarkBaker But when i write the `td->nodeValue` with `DOMDocument` it can not write it to cell, it may be cause of `DOMElement` ?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can render the view first to a variable then check if it has fontawesome icon example:

```
$myview = view('blade template')->render();

If(strpos($myview,'fa-check'))
{
  // we detected font awesome icon, do something.
}
```